# Interprocess communcation between docker and host system

Tags: python, apache, multiprocessing

I have a python program that does some machine learning. This is supposed to be accessible over network using HTTP. Since I want Apache to act as a server,I use a python script to send the data which is received to my program using python  `multiprocessing.connection`.

For eg script to send will be

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from multiprocessing.connection import Client
import cgi
from job import *

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
address = ('localhost', 6000)
conn = Client(address, authkey='secretpass')
conn.send(form)
```

And the receiving script will be

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener
import threading

print "Starting listener"
address = ('localhost', 6000)
listener = Listener(address, authkey='secretpass')
while True:
   conn = listener.accept()
   msg = conn.recv()
   conn.close()
   # Do stuff with msg
listener.close()
```

Once I trigger the url, Apache will call the first script, and it will send the python object to other script. Other script will receive it and do the processing.

Now, I would like to put the ML part into a docker container while Apache will be in the host system. In that case how will I communicate ?

Comment: Added note to clarify 
My question is : Can I use multiprocessing communication to communicate between a process running inside a docker container and another process in the host system ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of the Processing library you will find the process Queue. This structure exists to allow messages to be passed between processes. If you are working on Linux it is a matter of setting up a global variable and pushing messages. The pattern is usually: any process can post, and a single process reads. With two or more queues you can easily set up back and forth communications without worry about collisions or lost messages.

This becomes harder in Windows and other more restrictive systems, as there are no globals shared between processes, and no way to pass a complex structure at creation of a process. In Windows it is far easier to simply stick to threads.

Details of the multi-processing/threads in python can be found here:

[16.6. multiprocessing — Process-based “threading” interface](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: My question is : Can I use multiprocessing communication to communicate between a process running inside a docker container and another process in the host system ?

Comment: Again, the answer is simple if your are running on Linux or the Mac: Create a processing queue as a global variable, and any process should be able to access it to post or read. In either case it sounds like you have something really specific and uncommon here and your best bet is to mock up a prototype yourself.

Comment: Will try out and reply... Thanks